# Compiling Webassembly from C++ using Emscripten

Tags: c++, reactjs, webassembly

I am trying to compile various C++ files into wasm files to subsequently be embedded in a [website](http://lehighnumericalanalysis.com). The website is built with React, so I essentially need to find a way to embed wasm files in Javascript.

I am looking for insight about the best way to accomplish this task, whether it is fixing my current process or using something other than Emscripten entirely.

Here is what I have done so far:

I have used Emscripten to compile on Mac Ventura 13.1 with

```
em++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -Os -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -s BINARYEN_ASYNC_COMPILATION=0 -o add.wasm
```

The test.cpp is:

```
extern "C" {
    int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Finally, the Javascript is:

```
import React from 'react';

function Demo() {
  function instantiate(bytes, imports) {
    return WebAssembly.compile(bytes).then(m => new WebAssembly.Instance(m, imports));
  }
  var importObject = { imports: { i: arg => console.log(arg) } };  
  fetch('./add.wasm').then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(bytes => instantiate(bytes, importObject))
  .then(instance => instance.exports.e());
  return (
    <div>
      <p>First trial of embedding webassembly</p>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

When deployed on the website, this yields the following error: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThKCd.png)

Again, I am looking for expertise on either a new approach to embedding wasm files in the javascript or making a modification to my compilation or other code.

Answer (score 1):

The hex values in the error message start with 0x3c 0x21 which are ascii for < and !.   This means that you `add.wasm` file is likely an html file that starts with "<!doctype..".

The simplest way to use emscripten modules is to output a `.js` file (e.g. "emcc -o out.js") and then load that generated JS file.   The generated JS file with take care of loading the wasm file and providing any needed imports.